# No module named 'ale_py._ale_py' when importing gym - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-gym

I get an **No module named 'ale_py._ale_py'** error when doing **import gym** in Jupyter Notebook.

When I first tried importing gym it said No Module named 'gym', so then I added sys.path.append() and the code looked like this:

```
import sys

sys.path.append(path)

import gym
```

And now there is an error that looks like this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ale_py/__init__.py in <module>
     46 
     47 # Import native shared library
---> 48 from ale_py._ale_py import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ale_py._ale_py'
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

By the way everything works fine not in Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and after installing ale_py version 0.7, I do not have it anymore.

`pip install ale_py==0.7`